# Suitable pins for securing tool handle

Tags: hand-tools

I've got an old multi-axe where the wooden handle is missing on one side and and rotten on the other. It's held on purely with pins that are the same material (I assume steel given the rust) as the tool itself. I'm going to make two new handles for it and secure these using the same method, but am not sure exactly what to search for when looking to buy the pins to peen! What some steel smooth rod be suitable? I've attached a picture of the idea for context. Any other advice is appreciated - I'm intending to cut the wood on a bandsaw and then sand it to shape, and use my ball-peen hammer to peen the pins (or whatever they're  called! Knowing what something is and what it looks like but not it's name is a common problem I run into and can be very frustrating when shopping online for parts, so any tips with that are also appreciated! [image]

Comment: "rivet" may be the keyword you're looking for, but that may only get you things like pop-rivets these days.

Comment: Probably just plain rivets.

Comment: Rivets I always associate with blind rivets, but looking for solid rivets is turning up very little aside from ebay which is frustrating - was hoping to buy them from a 'proper shop'! Thanks :)

Comment: Solid rivets should be easy to find, google shows quite a few places.  Might also want to check rivet screws.

Comment: something like this may work ... https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71%2BQIsuxjWL.jpg ........ https://duckduckgo.com/?q=barrel+nuts&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

Answer (score 2):

Typical material used for these is brass or copper, but soft (unhardened) steel would also work if you don't mind the rust. {material} rod would be a typical search, though some thick wire can also work.

Or you could purchase actual rivets of appropriate length.

"copper rivet and burr" is one search term that will find a product arguably better and easier to peen into place than what you show, one common use of which is exactly this (making a slight counterbore on the surface of the knife scale for the head and burr to set into.)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any advantage to using rivets over rod?

Comment: You don't have to form the head side at all, and it's much quicker and easier to peen the rivet onto the burr (washer, basically) than to peen the rod out wide enough to hold securely on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea from out left field…
You could deep counter-sink & bolt it through, possibly even using parts you already own.

Comment: "Saw-Bolts" will do this approach neatly and without needing such a deep counterbore. Standard item for holding wooden saw handles on steel saws.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - ah, indeed. I hadn't even considered they were a separate item - pound each - https://www.flinn-garlick-saws.co.uk/acatalog/Saw_Screws_.html